# Vim and Spanish

Tags: keyboard-layout

Is there a vim adaptation (plugin) for the Spanish keyboard?

There is one for the [Russian language](https://github.com/powerman/vim-plugin-ruscmd), for instance. Of course, Russian is much more troublesome, because you have to remap virtually every key; Spanish is almost QWERTY, but not really. Periphery is quite different.

I made some research; nada. Perhaps, I just missed something.

Comment: Since there probably aren't many differences versus en_us keyboard it would be pretty easy to create your own "keymap". Look in the _keymap_ directory in your Vim installation dir. It has a number of languages. Pick a straightforward one (Croatian perhaps) and follow its lead (copy all "croation" files and modify for Spanish...see `:h keymap-file-format`). Then you'll be able to switch to/back using the `keymap` command.

Comment: Alternatively, you could go with a custom solution based on key mappings (i.e. `:map` et al). E.g. [Useful mapping to write some Spanish words in Vim](http://www.davideg.es/indexd06c.html?p=334)

Comment: So similar that it does not merit a *keymap*... I see. But what am I supposed to with colon commands? The colon is in use for things like ö.

Comment: Errr...`langmap` then (basically, reverts to native keys when in Normal mode)? I'm starting to wonder if I actually understand what you want to do. Does any of this help? https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4758/what-is-the-most-convenient-way-to-work-with-different-keyboards-in-vim?rq=1 . If not please provide more details about your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do make vim use a different keyboard layout is by setting the
option `keymap` in your `vimrc` file.

For more info checkout `:h keymap` inside vim.